# Pipe hex characters to awk

Tags: bash, awk

This command works as expected

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "\x41"}'
A
```

As does this

```
$ printf '\x41' | awk '{print}'
A
```

However when you rely on awk to recognize the hex characters, it fails

```
$ echo '\x41' | awk '{print}'
\x41
```

How can this be overcome?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just use `printf` as you have or `echo -e`. I assume your actual use case is more complex, could you give an example of what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Ah, crap then, the `-n` option (see `man gawk`) to `gawk` (not `awk` I think) seemed promising but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to do something like:

```
printf '%s\n' '\x41' | 
  awk 'BEGIN{for (i=0;i<0x100;i++) x[sprintf("%02x",i)]=sprintf("%c",i)}
       {print x[tolower(substr($0,3))]}'
```

`awk` can't take a hex string and convert it directly to a number, let alone a character.

That kind of thing is a lot easier done in `perl`. See [here](http://www.shelldorado.com/scripts/cmds/urldecode) for a `awk` implementation of `urldecode`.

As [hinted by @terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127420/pipe-hex-characters-to-awk#comment203966_127420), the GNU implementation of `awk` has a `-n|--non-decimal-data` option that allows `awk` to recognise hex and octal numbers on input. So you could also do:

```
printf '%s\n' '\x41' | gawk -n '{printf "%c\n", +("0x" substr($0,3))}'
```

`gawk` also has a `strtonum()` function:

```
printf '%s\n' '\x41' | gawk -n '{printf "%c\n", strtonum("0x" substr($0,3))}'
```